# return a character found in a pattern

Tags: cut

## GOAL

**What is the simplet one-liner that can read the disk number and perform the mount command?**

The one-liner will execute the equivalent of:

```
./mountEFI.command disk3
```

## BACKGROUND

user@mac ~ % diskutil list

returns

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨NO NAME⁩                 104.9 MB   disk0s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved ⁨⁩                        16.8 MB    disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨NTFS⁩                    127.4 GB   disk0s3
   4:           Windows Recovery ⁨⁩                        525.3 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1000.0 GB  disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨LANCE - Data⁩            60.7 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨LANCE⁩                   15.3 GB    disk2s3
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk2s3s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 309.8 MB   disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                620.4 MB   disk2s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk2s6

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *61.5 GB    disk3
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI_USB⁩                 209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Install macOS Monterey⁩  61.2 GB    disk3s2
```

Therefore:

```
diskutil list | grep '(external, physical)'
```

returns

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
     ^   ^
     6   10
```

The goal is to return characters 6-10,**disk3**.

The one-liner must execute the equivalent of:

```
./mountEFI.command disk3
```

**What is the simplet one-liner that can read the disk number and perform the mount command?**

## UPDATE

```
diskutil list -plist external physical
```

returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AllDisks</key>
    <array>
        <string>disk3</string>
        <string>disk3s1</string>
        <string>disk3s2</string>
    </array>
    <key>AllDisksAndPartitions</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Content</key>
            <string>GUID_partition_scheme</string>
            <key>DeviceIdentifier</key>
            <string>disk3</string>
            <key>OSInternal</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Partitions</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Content</key>
                    <string>EFI</string>
                    <key>DeviceIdentifier</key>
                    <string>disk3s1</string>
                    <key>DiskUUID</key>
                    <string>5F5C5E00-71B1-4259-B062-95683183898B</string>
                    <key>Size</key>
                    <integer>209715200</integer>
                    <key>VolumeName</key>
                    <string>EFI_USB</string>
                    <key>VolumeUUID</key>
                    <string>0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Content</key>
                    <string>Apple_HFS</string>
                    <key>DeviceIdentifier</key>
                    <string>disk3s2</string>
                    <key>DiskUUID</key>
                    <string>059700E8-2B72-4669-9030-7C783AA398FB</string>
                    <key>MountPoint</key>
                    <string>/Volumes/Install macOS Monterey</string>
                    <key>Size</key>
                    <integer>61186465792</integer>
                    <key>VolumeName</key>
                    <string>Install macOS Monterey</string>
                    <key>VolumeUUID</key>
                    <string>14B0CA5F-27B4-31E3-8096-9235338AFBBD</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>61530439680</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>VolumesFromDisks</key>
    <array>
        <string>Install macOS Monterey</string>
    </array>
    <key>WholeDisks</key>
    <array>
        <string>disk3</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You're using the right tool the wrong way. You can get a parseable list via `-plist`.  Post the output of `diskutil list -plist external physical`

Comment: @don_crissti  Thank you for the feedback.   Please see the `UPDATE`in the post above and respond with an answer below?  I look forward to your insight and your solution

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'd rather want the part between `"/dev/"` and `" (external, physical):"`, so:

```
diskutil list | sed -n 's|^/dev/\(.*\) (external, physical)$|\1|p'
```

`cut` can return a range of bytes from each line of some input, but that input has to be passed via its stdin, not as arguments so:

```
diskutil list | grep '(external, physical)' | cut -b 6-10
```

But that approach would fail for `disk10` and above or block devices whose name don't follow that pattern.

You can pass each line (assuming it doesn't contain apostrophes, doubles or backslashes) stripped of leading blanks as the one argument to separate invocations of `./mountEFI.command` using `xargs`:

```
diskutil list |
  sed -n 's|^/dev/\(.*\) (external, physical)$|\1|p' |
  xargs -I DISK ./mountEFI.command DISK
```

Comment: Brilliant!   I think I can pipe the result into mountEFI.command:   `diskutil list | grep '(external, physical)' | cut -b 6-10 |  myPath/mountEFI.command`  Is there a better method / syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk:

(I don't have a Mac, so I'm using a text file containing your sample output as the input to awk. Would work the same with `diskutil list | awk ...`)

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]' '/external, physical/ { print $3 }' /tmp/diskutil.list 
disk3
```

Using both `/` and   (space) as field separators, this awk script only prints the third field (`$3`) on any line matching "external, physical". Non-matching input lines aren't printed.

The first field is the empty string before the first `/`, the second is whatever is between the first and second `/` (`dev`), and the third is whatever is between the second `/` and the first space character (`disk3`).

---

To execute `./mountEFI.command` with each disk, you could use `xargs`:

```
diskutil list awk -F'[/ ]' '/external, physical/ { print $3 }' | xargs -L 1 ./mountEFI.command
```

The `-L 1` tells xargs to run `./mountEFI.command` *once for each line* if there's more than one line of output from awk.

Without the `-L 1`, `xargs` would try to run the command once (or as few times as possible if there are many thousands of lines, subject to ARG_MAX on your system...dunno what it is on a Mac but on Linux that's about 2 million characters, so "a lot". ) with as many arguments as it can (e.g. if disk0 and disk1 matched the pattern, xargs would run `./mountEFI.command disk0 disk1`) which won't work unless `./mountEFI.command` can loop over multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the good response.  Please consider commenting as to why you would use awk (new to me).  Thanks!

Comment: @gatorback because it's a good tool for extracting field data from lines matching particular patterns.  While `awk` is capable of a lot more than simple things like this, here it's one tool combining the desired features of both `grep` and `cut`.  it's good for lots of text processing / extraction tasks - although for more complex tasks or working with structured data like xml or json, or even csv (which is more than just simple comma-separated, it can have quoted fields and commas inside the quotes) I'd be inclined to use either specialised tools like `xmlstarlet` or `jq` or `perl`.